# SOAP Webservice Call gives 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: angularjs, soap, cors

I'm working on an Angular web application which consumes a third party SOAP web service.

I'm working with [Angualr-soap](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap) for SOAP calls.

Angularjs service code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularSoap']);

app.config([
    '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);

app.factory("CallSOAPService", ['$soap', function ($soap) {
    var baseListUrl = "http://***.***.***.***/WebBooking/ListingServices.asmx";

return {
    getCityList: function () {
        return $soap.post(baseListUrl, "GetCityList");
    }
}

}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'CallSOAPService', 
    function ($scope, CallSOAPService) {
    CallSOAPService.getCityList().then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function() {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });

}]);
```

It gives me following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://***.***.***.***/WebBooking/ListingServices.asmx?wsdl. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried the same call by installing `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:*` extension in chrome and it works fine.

I know that this chrome extension allow to request any site with ajax from any source, Adds to response `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header

I tried this same URL with ASP.NET Web Forms application and it doesn't give me this CORS issue.

Is there any other way of call this without getting this CORS issue rather than handling it from the Server?

Comment: if you want a definitive solution you have to act on server side

Comment: The issue is I have no control over server side. I can request it but it will take sometime to get this rectified in server.

Comment: You can put a proxy in front of the beckend server

Comment: What do u mean by putting a proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading few articles and also few R&D steps, found the solution for this. There are 2 possibilities for this.

As the best option We can enable CORS form service side. For that we can follow the following steps.

1. Open Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager
2. Right click the site you want to enable CORS for and go to
   Properties
3. Change to the HTTP Headers tab
4. In the Custom HTTP headers section, click Add
5. Enter Access-Control-Allow-Origin as the header name
6. Enter * as the header value
7. Click Ok twice

If we have no control over the server and we can achieve it through mock service. This mock service is only for calling the service which we have no control.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no way of doing this across the board. Some clients won't check CORS headers but for the ones that do, you have to fix it server-side. If there was a way of doing it client-side, it would defeat the entire purpose of CORS

Comment: When I do a request through ASP.Net Web Forms application it doesn't give me this error and also same when I call the web service when Allow-Control-Allow-Orgin:* extension. Can I get something out of it?

Answer (score -1):

In the config block you can use:-
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

However, it needs to be configured from the server as well to work

Comment: I tried it as well. Please check the updated question. Thanks